# Sql Multi-selecting one line from subgroups inside the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, multi-select

Given the following table:

```
id | group_s | name
_____________________
1  |   1   | pollo
2  |   1   | cordero
3  |   1   | cerdo
4  |   2   | tomates
5  |   2   | naranjas
6  |   2   | manzanas
```

I would like to randomly select one line from every group.
Example of possible outputs (since it is random):

```
id | group_s | name
_____________________
3  |   1   | cerdo
5  |   2   | naranjas
```

or

```
id | group_s | name
_____________________
1  |   1   | pollo
6  |   2   | manzanas
```

and so on..

I don't have a clue how to do it. I suppose I should multiselect the table.
I did try the following without success:

```
SELECT T2.* FROM (
SELECT group_s
FROM mytable
GROUP BY group_s ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) AS T1
JOIN mytable AS T2
ON T1.group_s = T2.group_s;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the window function `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY group_s)` with `ORDER BY NEWID()` to randomly get the ordering, something like this:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
   SELECT *,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY group_s 
                       ORDER BY newid()) AS RN
   FROM yourTable
)
SELECT id , group_s , name
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

See it in action here:

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/25efd/4)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am trying to make your statement to work under my server but it doesn't(I am copy pasting the statements after creating the corresponding tables). It shows an error 1064 -an error sql syntax-. And I see clearly under SQL Fiddle Demo is running. Could this be a mysql version problem?

Comment: @user903645 - I am sorry, I thought it is SQL Server, for MySQL I try to it but I could, I did it, but with the minimum for the `Id` not a random each time, see [this sql fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be046/16). I retagged your question with the MySQL tag, and wait for another answer. You can also unaccept this answer since it is not the correct answer. Also you can google for ***mysql row_number over partition by***, you will find a plenty of posts explaining how to do it.